# SQL Syntax on DISTINCT Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an Employee Table with their DeptCode. I want list of distinct DeptCode and their first created date in the Employee Table. This will also tell which employee was first entered for a specific dept in the Employee Table.

I used:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPTCODE, 
                CREATEDDATE 
FROM   EMPLOYEE
```

The Date Return is incorrect.

Any specific syntax to handle this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DEPTCODE, 
       Min(CREATEDDATE) 
FROM   EMPLOYEE 
GROUP  BY DEPTCODE
```

Comment: Does not specify the employee, which may be part of the question.

Comment: @DanBracuk he says "want list of distinct DeptCode and their first created date". It's also not in his current select list

Comment: Read the third sentence of the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the department codes, earliest creation date, *and* the name of the employee, then I would recommend window functions:

```
select deptcode, name, createddate
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by deptcode order by createddate) as seqnum
      from employee e
     ) e
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GROUP BY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) and [MIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx) to achieve this.

```
SELECT DEPTCODE, MIN(CREATEDDATE)
from EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY DEPTCODE
```

Comment: Does not specify the employee, which may be part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```
SELECT deptcode, 
       employee_name, 
       minddate 
FROM   employee 
       JOIN (SELECT deptcode, 
                    Min(createddate) mindate 
             FROM   employee 
             GROUP  BY deptcode) temp 
         ON employee.deptcode = temp.deptcode 
            AND createddate = mindate
```